# roscreate-stack: command not found [Hydro]

Tags: ros, stack, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

It's been a while i've been on ROS (from electric, and now on hydro). I can't seem to get roscreate-stack to work.
It simply says:
`roscreate-stack: command not found`

I understand this is not available in ros fuerte (as the wiki page says), but is it not available for Hydro too? I'm not fully understanding it.

Thank you, everyone.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128656/roscreate-stack:-command-not-found-%5Bhydro%5D/) by [Haikal Pribadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1779/haikal-pribadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hydro has moved to using catkin, and has moved away from stacks. Everything is a package now. To setup a skeleton package, use

```
catkin_create_pkg NAME [DEPENDENCY [DEPENDENCY [..]]]
```

in your source workspace.

Also, see the [catkin/CreatingPackage](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/catkin/CreatingPackage) page on the ROS wiki.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1